# quantile plot, two data - issues with fitting the line in R

Tags: r, plot

So I am trying to plot two p values from two different data frames and compare them to the normal distribution in QQplot in R

here is the code that I am using

```
## Taking values from 1st dataframe to plot
Rlogp = -log10(trialR$PVAL)
Rindex <- seq(1, nrow(trialR))
Runi <- Rindex/nrow(trialR)
Rloguni <- -log10(Runi)
## Taking values from 2nd dataframe to plot on existing plot
Nlogp = -log10(trialN$PVAL) 
Nlogp = sort(Nlogp) 
Nindex <- seq(1, nrow(trialN)) 
Nuni <- Nindex/nrow(trialN)
Nloguni <- -log10(Nuni) 
Nloguni <- sort(Nloguni) 
qqplot(Rloguni, Rlogp, xlim=range(0,6), ylim=range(0,6), col=rgb(100,0,0,50,maxColorValue=255), pch=19, lwd=2, bty="l",xlab ="", ylab ="") 
qqline(Rloguni, Rlogp,distribution=qnorm, lty="dashed")
par(new=TRUE, cex.main=4.8, col.axis="white") 
plot(Nloguni, Nlogp, xlim=range(0,6), ylim=range(0,6), col=rgb(0,0,100,50,maxColorValue=255), pch=19, lwd=2, bty="l",xlab ="", ylab ="")
```

The code plot the graph effectively,but I am not sure of the qqline as it seems bit offset... Can someone tell me if I am doing the correct way or is there something to change
[image: qqplot]

the TARGET plot will look something like this - without the third data value..
[image: target plot]

Comment: You need to explain what you think are doing on a step by step basis. (There's no point in applying log transformations when the goal is a qqplot since any monotonic transformation will not affect quantile distribution.)

Comment: See [qqman](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qqman/vignettes/qqman.html) package.